# Can I add a string to each string in an array without using a for loop?

Tags: c#

Can this be achieved without the for loop?

I know it'd involve interation behind the scenes but I wanted a concise one-liner if possible.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string[] strings = new string[] { "foo", "bar", "foobar" };
        for(int i = 0; i < strings.Length; i++)
        {
            strings[i] = strings[i] + "!";
        }
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", strings));
    }
```

Each string in my array (foo, bar, foobar) gets an exclamation mark!
Output: `foo! bar! foobar!`

(although the display bit isn't important here, I really want the string `!` added to each element in the array)

Comment: Using Linq : strings = strings.Select(str => str + "!").ToArray();

Comment: What do you imagine the alternative would be? Is there a reason you don't want to use `for`? Any solution will involve iterating over your array, but there are forms that don't "look" like a loop.

Comment: It's always Linq! Thanks you @User965207.

Comment: @Herohtar Yes I phrased it wrong. I know it'd involve interation behind the scenes but I wanted a concise one-liner if possible. I should've asked without the `for` loop

Comment: @jamheadart please add your last comment to you question for future users.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string[] strings = new string[] { "foo", "bar", "foobar" };
    var strings1 = strings.Select(xx=>xx + "!!");       
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", strings1));
}
```